# Android アプリverCode取得

Tags: android

端末にインストールされている
アプリのverCodeを取得する方法は無いでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、`PackageManager#getInstalledApplications`でインストールされているアプリの一覧を取得し、`getPackageInfo`で各アプリの詳細を取得します。

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> appInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appInfoList) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(appInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Log.v(TAG, appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString() + ":" + info.versionName + ":" + info.versionCode);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！！！

Comment: 実際にvercodeを取得する事が出来ました！